How to set telegram account privacy rules using Pyrogram?
I'm attempting to set privacy rules for a Telegram account using Pyrogram.
In the below code I've tried to set ChatInvite privacy to Nobody but I got an error:
import asyncio

from pyrogram import Client, raw


async def main():
    async with Client("authorization") as client:
        await client.invoke(
            raw.functions.account.SetPrivacy(
                key=raw.types.PrivacyKeyChatInvite(),
                rules=[raw.types.InputPrivacyValueDisallowAll()],
            )
        )


asyncio.run(main())

Here's the error I'm getting:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\nimaxin\Desktop\app\main.py", line 16, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "C:\Users\nimaxin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 190, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\nimaxin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\nimaxin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 653, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\nimaxin\Desktop\app\main.py", line 8, in main
    await client.invoke(
  File "C:\Users\nimaxin\Desktop\app\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pyrogram\methods\advanced\invoke.py", line 79, in invoke
    r = await self.session.invoke(
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\nimaxin\Desktop\app\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pyrogram\session\session.py", line 389, in invoke
    return await self.send(query, timeout=timeout)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\nimaxin\Desktop\app\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pyrogram\session\session.py", line 357, in send
    RPCError.raise_it(result, type(data))
  File "C:\Users\nimaxin\Desktop\app\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pyrogram\errors\rpc_error.py", line 91, in raise_it
    raise getattr(
pyrogram.errors.exceptions.bad_request_400.PrivacyKeyInvalid: Telegram says: [400 PRIVACY_KEY_INVALID] - The privacy key is invalid (caused by "account.SetPrivacy")

how can I correctly set the key and rules for this purpose?

Thanks to the help of some friends, I was able to find the solution to my question.
I should use pyrogram.raw.types.InputPrivacyKeyChatInvite instead of pyrogram.raw.types.PrivacyKeyChatInvite
